# Logging into Azure Ad with Cypress

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, cypress

How can I retrieve an access token via Azure authentication?

Comment: You can have a look into this - https://mechanicalrock.github.io/2020/05/05/azure-ad-authentication-cypress.html

Comment: I mentioned it in the he question it did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the Azure AD login by creating the following Cypress custom command:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => {
  return cy
    .request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/token`,
      form: true,
      body: {
        grant_type: 'password',
        tenant: 'tenantId',
        client_id: 'clientId',
        client_secret: 'clientSecret',
        username: 'username',
        password: 'password',
        resource: 'clientId',
      },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      sessionStorage.setItem('access_token', response.body.access_token);
    });
});
```

Then you can use your custom command in your test as first action like:

```
cy.login();
```

and then perform your site visit:

```
cy.visit()
```

Comment: Do you actually process / use the access_token you receive in the response to authenticate your user?

Comment: Thank you for this - managed to get it working

Comment: @Siduduzo Godfrey Manqele- Do you mind sharing your full solution?