# Cypress AzureAD authentication automation

Tags: azure-active-directory, cypress

how to implement the Automation of MS Azure Ad Authenticatio in cypress and we have to implement User based login into the Application so we need to login multiple times with different user name and password

Comment: Is the answer provided by kavyasaraboju-MT was helpful for you ? if so could you please accept the answer (click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in) as solution for your ask. This could be beneficial to other community members.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logging into Azure Ad with Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64822167/logging-into-azure-ad-with-cypress)

Answer (score 2):

> [Note:Small suggestion is that it might not be a good practice to  automate  login
> , as that action might be detected as a bot and block it, causing your
> tests to break.]

- In cypress code , custom commands can be used for authentication.These
  Commands are used for adding or overriding functionality within
  Cypress and are defined in the cypress/support/commands.js file by
  default.
- Can refer the below link for more information regarding AD authentication in cypress tests
  https://mechanicalrock.github.io/2020/05/05/azure-ad-authentication-cypress.html
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow
  is helpful article on authenticating with Azure AD specifically for
  service accounts without any form of user interaction.