# Unable to log in to azure ad with cypress

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, cypress

I tried to set access token in session storage as well as local storage, either does not work. Access token retrieved with below request:

```
cy.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`,
      form: true,
      body: {
        grant_type: 'password',
        tenant: '{tenantId}',
        client_id: '{clientid}',
        client_secret: '{client secret}',
        username: '{test user email Id}',
        password: '{test user password}',
        scope: 'user.read openid profile offline_access'
      },
    })
```

Cypress tries to hit the login url infinitely per logs. Test user is MFA exempted as well.
Chrome browser on local takes my login in normal mode and requires login only in incognito mode.

Firefox requires login but hits login API infinitely.

NOTE: I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64822167/logging-into-azure-ad-with-cypress) answer, does not work for me. I could not somehow add comment on that answer, so need to raise new question.
Also tried [this](https://mechanicalrock.github.io/2020/05/05/azure-ad-authentication-cypress.html) , does not work for me as I am using MSAL.

Comment: My project on GitHub might be helpful: https://github.com/juunas11/AzureAdUiTestAutomation. Cypress clears local and session storage between tests so that won't work as storage.

Comment: I was looking at the app registration and found `Allow public client flows` in authentication. Is it required to be enabled? I will try by enabling it.

Comment: After logging in to application from browser manually, I do not see the session storage and local storage has any key like `access_token` etc. Do I need to change anything in my angular application code?

Comment: I learned that my application is using EasyAuth feature and which is totally based on cookie "AppServiceAuthSession" by app service which will be added to each request by browser and  treated as authentication. So setting  session storage and local storage is not helpful in my case. Trying to find a way to get this cookie and set in browser. No luck yet. Any help much appreciated.